# Include foreign key in composite primary key in Code-First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have an Entity named `Member`, for which I would like to set a primary key of `MemberId` and `GroupId`. In this case, `GroupId` is the primary key of the entity `Group`. With the code below, the foreign key is set correctly, but it is not included as part of the primary key. How can I have the foreign key column added to make a composite primary key?

```
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public string MemberId { get; set; }

    public string MemberName { get; set; }

    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Composite). Simply use the `[Key]` annotation on all the properties you want to include in the composite key and add an extra `[Column(Order=x)]`attribute for those columns.

```
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string MemberId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    public string MemberName { get; set; }     

    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```